# establishing a database connection

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

My database is named 'login'. This is the php statement that is used in my login.php/register.php files (saved to htdocs)which is supposed to establish a database connection.

```
$this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

I want to make sure I connect successfully so i assume I have to change these

```
(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
```

to this

```
('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'login');
```

The only problem is i get thrown off with the naming conventions  i.e. 'localhost', 'root', 'root', etc . This is what's listed on my mamp start up page

```
Host    localhost
Port    3306
User    root
Password    root
Socket  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

These are the examples listed on my mamp start up page for using the info

```
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'inventory'; //what is this?
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;

$link = mysql_connect(
"$host:$port", 
$user, 
$password
);
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(
$db, 
$link
);
```

does this mean i should configure login/register.php to;

```
$this->db_connection = new mysqli  ('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'login');
```

or is it done this way?

```
$this->db_connection = new mysqli  ('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'login');
```

This was in the configuration file db.php which is supposed to be saved in the same directory for my application;

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("DB_NAME", "login");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "mysql");
?>
```

I thought that

```
'DB_HOST',
'DB_NAME',
'DB_USER',
'DB_PASS'
```

were space fillers meant to be edited and changed but does this mean i can keep the original line;

```
$this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

If i save db.php in the same directory? Or again, could i or should i edit it to read something like;

```
define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1"); **** define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "login");     **** define("DB_NAME", "login");
define("DB_USER", "root");      **** define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "mysql");     **** define("DB_PASS", "root"); //i.e. my password has never been mysql
```

I was also wondering if this line would act as a reliable constant;

```
grant all privileges on login.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'root'; //or should it be identified by 'password'?
```

Comment: `DB_HOST`, `DB_MAME`..., in this case, are constants, you change / edit them by changing the 2nd attribute in `define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");`, meaning you replace the `127.0.0.1` for example with whatever you need...

Comment: in layman's terms: **host** = server where the database is hosted, **port** = "door" on the server, **db** = name of the database, **user** = the username used to login to the database, **password** = the password used to login to the database

Comment: @webeno in that case would changing define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1"); to define("DB_HOST", "localhost"); be valid?

Comment: yes, it would be valid, but that's not necessarily needed, as 127.0.0.1 is the same as localhost... it doesn't harm to try, so go ahead...